# Moving components relative to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I have 4 JButton setted underneath eachother. I want them to move right and left when the user resizes the frame horizontely.

eg: Frame size: 400,400 
    ButtonLocation: 300,200

Now I Resize the frame to : 600,400
ButtonLocation should be: 500,200

Any Idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use proper LayoutManager. E.g. GridBagLayout where you can set  fill and Insets to GridBagConstraints for each button.

Answer (score 1):

To get 4 buttons underneath each other, put them in a single column [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html).  To get then to move relative to the RHS of the frame, put the (panel with the `GridLayout`) into the `EAST` constraint of a [`BorderLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).

See [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) for more details.